# How to view status of recent AppEngine mapreduce jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, mapreduce

We recently upgraded our App Engine application to GAE SDK 1.9, and upgraded the older MapReduce library we'd been using to the most recent version hosted on GitHub. We now find that the old MapReduce status page (http://.appspot.com/mapreduce/status) doesn't show the various daily jobs that we run.

The current GoogleCloudPlatform MapReduce doc (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/2.2-Monitoring-a-Job) describes a monitoring page that should be accessible at http://.appspot.com/_ah/pipeline/list -- but this gives a 'Requested URL ... not found on this server' message.

Is the URL described in the doc incorrect, or is this monitoring page no longer supported?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python use /mapreduce/pipeline/list

Any issues about the mapreduce library should be posted on their [issues page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/issues).